# Approximating zeros of $\tan(x) = 1/x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, roots

I am a PDE university student and learning about the Wave equation:

$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$$

We are applying boundary conditions of the third kind:

$$ \begin{cases}
u_x(0,t)-u(0,t) = 0, \\
u_x(1,t) = 0.
\end{cases} $$

Using separation of variables for $X$ we get:

$$ X(x) = \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + 
\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x). $$

Applying boundary conditions to this we get:

$$ \bbox[color:navy; border:1px dotted navy; padding:5px;]{ \tan(\sqrt{\lambda}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} }$$

In class, we just use `Desmos` to get values of $\lambda$ but I was trying to find a way to approximate $\lambda$ using series:

> Let $\sqrt{\lambda}=x$.
>
> $$ \tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}.$$
>
> Using $\sin$ and $\cos$ series
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sin(x) &= \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}, &
> \cos(x) &= \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n},
> \end{align*}
>
> we get:
>
> \begin{align*}
> & \tan(x) = \frac{\sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}}{\sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}} = \frac{1}{x} \\
> &\quad\iff\quad
> \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n} \\
> &\quad\iff\quad
> \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} = \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n-1} \\
> &\quad\iff\quad
> \sum_{n=0} \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} - \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n-1} \right) = 0 \\
> &\quad\iff\quad
> \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n \left( \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(2n+2)!} \right)x^{2n+1} = 0.
> \end{align*}

At this step I am not sure where to go next. I have a simple polynomial and the $\frac{1}{x}$ term, I was hoping I could selectively pick values of $n$ for the summation to get values for $\lambda_n$ but I don't know how to procedurally solve this summation. Any help or advice appreciated :)

Comment: Would a method besides your “simple polynomial” method work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are using this method, I'd probably recommend doing something like transforming $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \tan x = \frac{1}{x}$ into something like $x\sin x - \cos x = 0$, so that you are essentially looking for zeros of the function $f(x) = x\sin x - \cos x$. This is a very common first step for solving intersections because now we are looking at a function that is defined everywhere and actually has a reasonable power series expansion:
$$f(x) = x\sin x - \cos x = x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} = -1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{2n+1}{(2n)!}  \right)x^{2n} $$
Now to approximate a root, we could truncate the series to get a polynomial, say $f(x) \approx -1 + \frac{3}{2}x^2$, which has the roots $x = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \approx .8165$ compared to the true value of $.8603$. The quartic polynomial $f(x) \approx -1 + \frac{3}{2}x^2 - \frac{5}{24}x^4$ does a bit better with root $x = \sqrt{\frac{18-2\sqrt{51}}{5}} \approx .8622$. But in general you can see that this is not a good method for approximating $\lambda_n$ because it requires solving for roots of polynomials, and also the McLauren series is centered at 0 so this doesn't even get close to solving any other solution to $\tan x = 1/x$, only the one closest to $x = 0$. You are much better off using any basic root finding algorithm on $f(x) = x\sin x - \cos x$, such as Newton's method, to approximate roots then a Taylor's series method. It also allows you to find any root you want as long as your initial guess is close enough, and since $\tan x = 1/x \approx 0$ for large $x$, any initial value slightly larger than $n \pi$ for $n$ an integer will zoom in on $\lambda_n^2$ rather quickly with Newton's method.

Edit: I just want to summarize I guess, the best way to numerically calculate the value $\lambda_n^2$ is to use Newton's method on $f(x) = x\sin x -\cos x$ with starting guess $n\pi$. The only exception is $\lambda_0^2$, the root closest to the origin, which is approximately $.8622$ but can also be found by Newton's method using a starting value somewhat close to this.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense, I was looking into this and hoping there would be a more analytical method but Newton's method seems to be a reasonable method.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrew answered, because of discontinuities induced by the tangent function, it is much easier to search for the zeros of function
$$f(x)=x \sin(x)-\cos(x)$$ Expanded around $x=n\pi$ and simplifying since $n$ is an integer we have
$$f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+n}\frac{\pi  n  (x-\pi  n)^{2 k+1}}{\Gamma (2
   k+2)}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+n}\frac{(2 k+1)  (x-\pi  n)^{2 k}}{\Gamma (2
   k+1)} $$

Truncating to some order and using series reversion
$$x_{(n)}=q+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{4}{3 q^3}+\frac{53}{15 q^5}-\frac{1226}{105
   q^7}+\frac{1739191}{40320 q^9}-\frac{22821}{128
   q^{11}}+\frac{50787}{128 q^{13}}-\frac{938223}{128
   q^{15}}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^{17}}\right)$$ where $q=n\pi$.

This is a very good approximation except for the very first root $x_{(0)}$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & \color{red}{3.425}30258165471 & 
     3.42561845948173 \\
 2 & \color{red}{6.4372981}4686411 & 
     6.43729817917195 \\
 3 & \color{red}{9.529334405}08961 & 
     9.52933440536196 \\
 4 & \color{red}{12.6452872238}450 &
     12.6452872238566 \\
 5 & \color{red}{15.77128487481}48 & 
     15.7712848748159 \\
 6 & \color{red}{18.9024099568}598 & 
     18.9024099568600 \\
 7 & \color{red}{22.036496727938}5 & 
     22.0364967279386 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you are not requiring too much accuracy, you can transform the series into a simple Padé approximant and use

$$x_{(n)}=q+\frac{1}{q}\,\frac{60 q^2+79}{60 q^2+159}$$ whose error is $\frac{1619}{700 q^7}$.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think about expanding about $n\pi$, smart and also probably more in line with what the question was asking for. But how quick is it actually to calculate the coefficients for the rational function in $q$? I wonder how preferable this would be (with the obvious advantage of being able calculate any value once you have the formula) to just using Newton's method for individual roots as needed

Comment: @Andrew. This is pretty standard with trigonometric functions and not very hard. To make you happy, I wrote something simpler. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks this is really cool!!  What is meant by expanding around x=npi?

Comment: @WilliamDelGiudice. Same idea as starting Newton at $x=n\pi$